Generador de plantillas de video con python
Estuve analizando un generador de plantillas de video en python
por medio de este repositorio:https://github.com/fbsamples/video-template-builder
seguí todos los requisitos indicados en el mismo:

Crear un entorno virtual
Activar dicho entorno.
Instalar las dependencias(ejecutar esta opción o las 2 anteriores juntas)

Los comandos que utilice en Windows son:

python -m venv myenv.
myenv\Scripts\activate

Me incline por la primera opción.
Pero al momento de ejecutar el archivo: main.py para probar el caso de prueba
la terminal arroja este error:
(myenv) C:\Users\pc\Downloads\Script\video-template-builder-main\src>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 6, in 
from source import *
File "C:\Users\pc\Downloads\Script\video-template-builder-main\src\source.py", line 6, in 
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Al parecer es un error en el archivo main.py
Desde ya muchas gracias por su atención!

"Instalar las dependencias(ejecutar esta opción o las 2 anteriores juntas)"? Creo que has malinterpetado las instrucciones,  tienes que ejecutar las tres, despues de crear el entorno y activarlo, debes instalar las dependecias en él(pip install -r requirements.txt). Lo que es opcional es crear un entorno (aunque siempre recomendable), pero las dependecias tienes que instalarlas, el error se produce porque no tienes instalada una de ellas (OpenCV)..

Es decir, los pasos deberian ser algo asi: 1. Abres una terminal en donde quieras tener tu venv  2. python -m venv myenv 3. myenv\Scripts\activate 4. cd C:\Users\pc\Downloads\Script\video-template-builder-main 5. python -m pip install -r requirements.txt 6. cd src  7. python main.py

Hola buenas tardes realice, todos los pasos indicados y luego de ejecutar dicho archivo me tira este error la terminal:
File "C:\Users\Gaston\Downloads\Script video\video-template-builder-main\src\main.py", line 32, in 
file_name = download(url, f"/tmp/{i}")
File "C:\Users\Gaston\Downloads\Script video\video-template-builder-main\src\main.py", line 17, in download
with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/0.png'

Asumo que se presenta ya que la ruta es /tmp/, es un directorio del sistema Unix para archivos temporales, pero no es un directorio que exista de manera predeterminada en Windows.
Para resolver este problema, puedes hacer lo siguiente:
Entonces modifique la ruta del archivo temporal: cambiando la ruta de /tmp/{i} a un directorio temporal que exista en Windows, como C:\Users\Gaston\Downloads\temp{i}                                                                 Pero igualmente me sigue generando otro error
